# WebView inside Fragment - Back button?

Tags: android, webview

I created a small Android 4 application with fragments. 
In all these fragments I have some webviews and if I click a different fragment I want a different website to load.

I have right now `TabOne.java` ; `TabTwo.java` ; `TabThree.java` and so on.

I was also wondering : Can I make this application without needing a `TabOne.java`, `TabTwo.java` and so on; only from `MainActivity.java`? I mean, to have a single `WebView`, and when clicking different Tabs, this `WebView` to load different Url (according to the selected Tab).
If this is not possible, can you tell me what is wrong here (`TabOne.java`) :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabone, container, false);
    myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.stirileprotv.ro");
    myWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack())                              
            {
                        myWebView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
            }
    });
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("m.stirileprotv.ro")) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
         }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did.

In the fragment, declare the webview reference as static-

```
public static WebView mWebView;

public WebFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a         browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;
}
public boolean canGoBack() {
    return mWebView.canGoBack();
}

public void goBack() {
    mWebView.goBack();
}
```

}

Now, In the parent activity -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    WebFragment fragment = new WebFragment();
    if (fragment.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        fragment.mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was implement it within the activity and then have a public static so:

In the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    public static WebView myWebView;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourtag") != null) {
            if(myWebView.canGoBack())
                myWebView.goBack();
            else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
    ...
}
```

and to reference it within the fragment:

```
MainActivity.myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

and be sure when you create the fragment you add a tag

```
transaction.replace(R.id.yourfragid, newfragment, "yourtag");
```